# Утечка памяти в асинхронном скрипте (memory leaks)

Tags: python, asyncio, утечка-памяти

Есть скрипт, который в асинхронном режиме слушает udp-порты с помощью библиотеки **asyncio_dgram**:

```
ss = await asyncio_dgram.bind((listen_ip, self.port))
```

В цикле, поступившая информация пишется в лог (в файл и консоль):

```
while True:
    try:
        data, addr = await ss.recv()
        self.logger.debug('{}'.format(data.hex()))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

При запуске скрипта видно, что и в консоль, и в файлы информация записывается (объём файлов с логами растёт). Запускаю **htop** и вижу, как с течением времени скрипт потребляет всё больше и больше оперативной памяти. В конечном итоге выполнение скрипта приостанавливается, либо обработка начинает занимать очень долгое время, так как израсходавана вся оперативная память. Но сам скрипт не останавливается, не выбрасывается какое-либо исключение.
Подскажите, где может происходить утечка памяти?
Спасибо.

Comment: Зачем вам эта библиотека если есть asyncio.Protocol?

Comment: Из-за малого опыта работы с asyncio я не знаю как реализовать мой скрипт с помощью asyncio.Protocol

Comment: @Cenzor быстрее прочитать документацию по asyncio, чем искать и исправлять утечки в чужой библиотеке.